# How to set variable in PHP twig Template Engine

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am using Twig Template Engine and I am new to using this framework. I would like to set the title of the page to "HomePage".

I am not able to do it. Here is the code snippet of PHP/HTML :

```
$template = $loader->getTemplate('index.html');
$renderArr['title_name'] = "My Home Page";
$renderArr['seq'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$template->display($renderArr);
```

HTML

```
    {% include 'header.html' %}     
    <title>{{ title_name }}</title> <!-- Not working -->

  <!-- Working -->
  {% for item in seq %}
    <li>${item|escape}</li>
  {% endfor %}
```

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: is the page rendering just missing your variable or is it not loading?

Comment: It is loading the page, but, it does not replace the title_name, It is still showing as {{ title_name }} on the browser

Comment: I believe `display()` just output the template directly, you should use `render()` instead.

Comment: you need to name your files with the extension .html.twig

Comment: @oligan, I am not sure, if that is the case. I am able to iterate through an array. I am modifying my question. I am not able to display just the variable, you know

Comment: use `render` not `display`. Did u turn debug on? @Oligan Thats not true

Comment: `$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true));`

Comment: okayy mb didnt know that ! so yes op use 
return `$this->render('AcmeMyBundle:..:.html', array('var1' => $var1, 'var2'=>$var2));`

Comment: Is there a reason you don't follow the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates)?

Comment: What does it show in output for title? You may overwrite the title tag by including `{% include 'header.html' %}`!